# What is causing tidyr warning message: "attributes are not identical across measure variables"

Tags: r, tidyr, tidyverse

I have a `tibble`, `df`:

```
> df
# A tibble: 4 x 5
    profile Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
      <chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1 Profile 1       -1.011       0.850       -1.301      -1.251
2 Profile 2        0.542      -0.389        0.662       0.673
3 Profile 3       -0.376      -0.967        0.115       0.038
4 Profile 4        1.502       0.158        1.277       1.239
```

When I use `tidyr::gather(), as follows:

```
tidyr::gather(df, var, val, -profile)
```

The following error is returned:

```
Warning message: attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped
```

I did some searching (and checked to see whether `df` has any attributes that might be causing the issue), but can't understand why this warning is being printed.

```
df <- structure(list(profile = c("Profile 1", "Profile 2", "Profile 3", 
"Profile 4"), Sepal.Length = structure(c(-1.011, 0.542, -0.376, 
1.502), .Dim = c(150L, 1L), "`scaled:center`" = 5.84333333333333, "`scaled:scale`" = 0.828066127977863), 
    Sepal.Width = structure(c(0.85, -0.389, -0.967, 0.158), .Dim = c(150L, 
    1L), "`scaled:center`" = 3.05733333333333, "`scaled:scale`" = 0.435866284936698), 
    Petal.Length = structure(c(-1.301, 0.662, 0.115, 1.277), .Dim = c(150L, 
    1L), "`scaled:center`" = 3.758, "`scaled:scale`" = 1.76529823325947), 
    Petal.Width = structure(c(-1.251, 0.673, 0.038, 1.239), .Dim = c(150L, 
    1L), "`scaled:center`" = 1.19933333333333, "`scaled:scale`" = 0.762237668960347)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .Names = c("profile", 
"Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"))
```

EDIT:

When I print `df`, it looks fine:

```
> df
# A tibble: 2 x 5
    profile Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
      <chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1 Profile 1       -1.011       0.850       -1.301      -1.251
2 Profile 2        0.506      -0.425        0.650       0.625
```

However, when I run `dput(df)`, and then run the code that it output (the same code as above), the error identified by @neilfws is returned.

Comment: I think there's an issue with your example data:

     "Error in attributes(.Data) <- c(attributes(.Data), attrib) : 
      dims [product 150] do not match the length of object [4]"

Comment: Hm, that's beguiling. When I print the data (example data), it prints fine (see edit above). But, when I then use dput(df), and then execute that output, the same error you found is returned.

Comment: The original iris data is 150 rows; maybe you used a subset to create the example data but the 150 has carried over somehow?

Comment: Hm, I aggregated the data using `dplyr::group_by()` and `dplyr::summarize()`.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this recently, and have some thoughts I could add that might be helpful for future reference for others.

Agree with @neilfws that one of the attribute errors is due to having `.Dim = c(150, 1L)` in the column attributes - referring to 150 rows of `iris` data, but this subset has only 4 rows of data.

However, the warning that was returned (also in the post title):

> Warning message: attributes are not identical across measure
>   variables; they will be dropped

refers to attributes being dropped when combining `data.frame` columns with `gather`, since they are not completely identical. The `df` in this post does have attributes which appear from being `scaled`:

```
R> str(df)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   4 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ profile     : chr  "Profile 1" "Profile 2" "Profile 3" "Profile 4"
 $ Sepal.Length: num [1:4, 1] -1.011 0.542 -0.376 1.502
  ..- attr(*, "`scaled:center`")= num 5.84
  ..- attr(*, "`scaled:scale`")= num 0.828
 $ Sepal.Width : num [1:4, 1] 0.85 -0.389 -0.967 0.158
  ..- attr(*, "`scaled:center`")= num 3.06
  ..- attr(*, "`scaled:scale`")= num 0.436
 $ Petal.Length: num [1:4, 1] -1.301 0.662 0.115 1.277
  ..- attr(*, "`scaled:center`")= num 3.76
  ..- attr(*, "`scaled:scale`")= num 1.77
 $ Petal.Width : num [1:4, 1] -1.251 0.673 0.038 1.239
  ..- attr(*, "`scaled:center`")= num 1.2
  ..- attr(*, "`scaled:scale`")= num 0.762
```

But this is just a *warning* - it will still work, but you lose the `attr` information since it varies across the variables when combined.

If you have a similar `data.frame` without these `attr` - for example:

```
structure(list(profile = structure(1:4, .Label = c("Profile 1", 
"Profile 2", "Profile 3", "Profile 4"), class = "factor"), Sepal.Length = c(-1.011, 
0.542, -0.376, 1.502), Sepal.Width = c(0.85, -0.389, -0.967, 
0.158), Petal.Length = c(-1.301, 0.662, 0.115, 1.277), Petal.Width = c(-1.251, 
0.673, 0.038, 1.239)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

then `gather` will work without any warning.

Also, as of latest `tidyr`, it is recommended to use `pivot_longer` instead of `gather` as `gather` will not be maintained.

```
library(tidyr)

pivot_longer(df, cols = -profile, names_to = "var", values_to = "val")
```